# How to change JavaFX slider thumb color without CSS

Tags: java, css, scala, javafx

I'm using ScalaFX, which is currently proving itself to be thoroughly useless and bugging out anytime I try to use css. Is there any way to change the fill color of a `Slider` without using css, or at least without separate css files?

I've managed to change the track color with `slider.setStyle("-fx-control-inner-background: #f08080;")`, but can't get the thumb working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the `-fx-base` property, which sets the component colors palette according to the value you specify.

Example:

```
slider.setStyle("-fx-base: #f08080;");
```

Result:

[image: Slider example]

However why don't you consider using a CSS file? It simplifies everything and allows you to make a lot more customizations. Take a look at the [Slider JavaFX CSS reference](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#slider), I think you will find what you're looking for.

Comment: That's really helpful thanks. I would absolutely love to be using CSS files, but I really can't seem to get them to work with ScalaFX. I've tried putting them pretty much everywhere I can in my sbt directory structure, but ScalaFX still doesn't find them.